# IPN paypal integration

Tags: asp.net, paypal, transactions, paypal-ipn

I have a question that .
When a transaction is done . Sometimes it show the status "Pending" on ipn. 
and when after few days that transection is completed does it provide the similar transaction id as provided earlier ?
I mean
When transaction is pending it provide Transaction id = "*******"
and When that transaction get completed will provide some transaction id ="*******"
does both the transaction id are similar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes transaction id remain same, during the life cycle of transaction, peding, cancelled , completed etc.